# spark-shell, dependency jars and class not found exception

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

I'm trying to run my spark app on spark shell. Here is what I tried and many more variants after hours of reading on this error...but none seem to work.

```
spark-shell --class my_home.myhome.RecommendMatch —jars /Users/anon/Documents/Works/sparkworkspace/myhome/target/myhome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,/Users/anon/Documents/Works/sparkworkspace/myhome/target/original-myhome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

What is get instead is

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my_home.myhome.RecommendMatch
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:229)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:695)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Any ideas please? Thanks!

UPDATE:
Found that the jars must be colon(:) separated and not comma(,) separated as described in several articles/docs

```
spark-shell --class my_home.myhome.RecommendMatch —jars /Users/anon/Documents/Works/sparkworkspace/myhome/target/myhome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/anon/Documents/Works/sparkworkspace/myhome/target/original-myhome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

However, now the errors have changed. Note ls -la finds the paths although the following lines complain that don't exit. Bizarre..

```
Warning: Local jar /Users/anon/Documents/Works/sparkworkspace/myhome/target/myhome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/anon/Documents/Works/sparkworkspace/myhome/target/original-myhome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar does not exist, skipping.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:314)
at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:268)
```

UPDATE 2:

```
spark-shell  —class my_home.myhome.RecommendMatch —-jars “/Users/anon/Documents/Works/sparkworkspace/myhome/target/myhome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/anon/Documents/Works/sparkworkspace/myhome/target/original-myhome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar”
```

The above command yields the following on spark-shell.

```
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use    setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/05/16 01:19:08 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop   library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/05/16 01:19:13 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp,  returning NoSuchObjectException
Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.0.101:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1494877749685).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_121)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :load my_home.myhome.RecommendMatch 
That file does not exist

scala> :load RecommendMatch 
That file does not exist

scala> :load my_home.myhome.RecommendMatch.scala 
That file does not exist

scala> :load RecommendMatch.scala
That file does not exist
```

The jars don't seem to be loaded :( based on what I see at http://localhost:4040/environment/

Answer (score 0):

The URLs supplied to `--jars` must be separated by commas. Your first command is correct.

You also have to add the jar at last param to spark-submit. Lets say `my_home.myhome.RecommendMatch` is part of **myhome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar** jar file.

```
spark-submit --class my_home.myhome.RecommendMatch \
—jars "/Users/anon/Documents/Works/sparkworkspace/myhome/target/original-myhome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" \ 
/Users/anon/Documents/Works/sparkworkspace/myhome/target/myhome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```